# How to stream data from mongodb to R?

Tags: r, mongodb, stream, shiny

We are constantly saving data from external devices into mongodb. Now I would like to analyze/visualize the incoming stream of data with Shiny. As for right now, I am importing the data once a second into R with the `find` argument from the mongolite library:

```
[...]
timestamp.start <- reactive({as.numeric(Sys.time()) - (3600 * input$history)})

sourceData <- reactive({
    invalidateLater(1000,session)
    nodes <- nodes.mongo$find(paste('{"timestamp" : {"$gt" :', timestamp.start(), '} }'))
    nodes
    })
[...]
```

But this is obviously this is not a good way to do it, since the answers getting bigger and bigger.

So the question is, is there a way to stream the new incoming data at the database to R/Shiny? If so, how?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you provide a bit more of the use case behind this Shiny app? Currently I don't see the issue as each time the shiny app session is refreshed it will re-query and add in the new data.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just run a db query to get the last entry in the collection, then rbind them to your data frame. This way you are keeping resources low on your query. You still can check it every second without issue of heavy data.